# Formatting features window cannot be closed

Tags: 2011, cme, chrome

When I use Chrome or Firefox to edit the formatting features of a rich text field from the schema window, the popup shows up normally but I cannot close the popup. As a result, it is not possible to change the formatting features.

The console (Chrome) shows the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified. FormattingFeatures_v6.1.0.55920.12_.aspx?mode=js:16
DisplayController.setup: Completed loading the page at 187ms. FormattingFeatures_v6.1.0.55920.12_.aspx?mode=js:22
31
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters.
```

IE works fine, so there is a work-around.

I'm using 2011SP1 HR1. Is this a known issue?

Comment: You could try turning off minification and seeing the line it breaks on.

Comment: If this happens without any customizations on a supported browser (it seems like that), you should report it to customer support.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This is one of the unanswered questions on our site so I was curious if we could solve the mystery :)

Comment: No, sorry Peter. Maybe it was a browser incompatibility, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember. This was a year ago, and I don't work for that customer anymore. I have voted to close the question.

Comment: it`s sdl code issue.please raise support ticket.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is very old question and even who asked wanted to close

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too old to solve and most likely not even relevant anymore